# does NPP_Write processes content before delivering it to plugin instance?

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, browser, npapi, browser-plugin

The code below should be self explanatory

```
NPP_PostURLNotify() //post to a URL that returns a pure java script code 
NPP_WriteReady()  
NPP_Write()  // when the browser calls back this function does it execute that java script before calling this function?
```

UPDATE: Ok, i spent some time and figured that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it doesn't. It feeds raw contents to the plugin.

Comment: It is not specified in the NPAPI specification, which means that different browsers and different versions of those browsers may implement it differently.  This is really a bad way to call javascript anyway; use NPN_Evaluate or GetValue the window object and call functions.

Comment: I tested this on safari ,chrome and firefox, they all feed raw data. Why is it bad way to call though?

Comment: Because it's much slower than all of the other ways, much less direct.  It goes through a bunch of weird hoops rather than directly executing the javascript.

Comment: Does this hold true for Windowless plugins? +1 for spec info

Comment: Windowless or windowed plugins is just how it is drawn; has nothing to do with the javascript interface.  I can't give you spec links on speed differences, only my own a) intuition (because it makes sense that using JS directly is faster) and b) experience (because I actually have benchmarked the performance using javascript through a URL call vs javascript through NPN_Evaluate and the direct route was *way* faster). I haven't done these tests recently, but I don't know why you'd want to use a URL when you can use NPN_Evaluate